# Throw an object using physics? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

So, I have been working for 4+ hours now, and I am trying to make an object that the player can throw. I was thinking of like tossing it, (not throwing it far, like .5 meters,) and I can’t seem to get it. I have tried adding force through rigidbody, making an animation, and just changing its transform. Can anyone help me if has anyone had to do something similar, if so how did you do it?

I don’t have any code examples, because nothing worked. (Please don’t just say Rigidbody, can you give examples. Thanks.)

Comment: Have you tried to use ForceMode.Impulse ?

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots, possibly the code you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still unable to add comments due to reputation, so here is a generic approach to setting up a rigidbody to be thrown based on mouse input.

```
 Camera cam;
 Rigidbody r;
 Vector3 direction = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
 r.AddForce(direction * 100);
```

The code is using the camera of your scene, the rigidbody of the object you want to throw, it then converts the screen space of the mouse input to a raycast to get a direction to throw the object, then adds a force on that object in that direction.

If you code looks something like this, there is a good chance you are changing the velocity or transform of the object elsewhere. It could also be colliding with another object and be getting stopped.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for more like when you press a button, an object would instantiate, (I did that part already) and then it would be tossed forward in a non-changeable direction. This is for a grenade I am making, and I want it to be a sort of object that sticks to what it hits (I did that already too).

Comment: @ken I would spawn the object so that the forward direction is the direction you click. If you are instantiating the object then change the direction to face the direction you just clicked (forward direction), then just add the force in the transform.Forward instead. It should fly in the direction you previously clicked.

Comment: I didn't understand that is what it was meant for. I just used cam.transform.rotation, is it better to use what you did?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you used for the add force? In what way is the add force not working? I would try the above snippet, but before adding force change the direction to the forward direction of where you are looking.

Comment: Instantiate(GrenadeObject, transform.position, PlayerRot.rotation, GrenadeParent);

Comment: rb.AddForce(direction * rbForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Impulse);

Comment: Two questions and a comment. What is direction? At this point you should just multiply by transform.forward if you are facing the direction you want the object go fly in. My question, why are you multiply by Time.deltaTime? This value is generally `0.016666667` or the time that has passed since the last frame (this value is 60 fps). Remove this and the force will work again. You are multiplying by a very small value due to the Time.deltaTime. Add force is immediate and is then handled by the physics engine. If you want to continually add force this is now how it is done.

Comment: direction is the Vector3 used for tweaking the angle of the toss. And thanks I'll try it, but I won't remove Time.deltaTime because I think it is important; I'll just change the force.

Comment: I can assure you that is your issue. It is not important, it is causing your force to go down to a near 0 value. I can bet you that is your issue, just remove it.

Comment: I added the RBforce to like 250 and it works. Thank You :)

Comment: You do not need to add 250. Again, the reason the number is so large to change it is because you are multiplying by Time.deltaTime. This is a value that is the amount of seconds since the last frame. A normal refresh rate is 60fps or 1/60 frames. What this means is you are multiplying this value by 1/60 or 0.016666667. You are effectively adding a force of 4.16666675 instead of 250. Try removing the Time.deltaTime.

Comment: Time.deltaTime is generally only used to multiply a value when you are adding increments of it in a Lerp. Add force is added in a single frame, then handled by the physics engine. It adds a single force (F = ma) and the a (acceleration) is applied causing your velocity to be effected over some time and other external forces (drag, friction, etc.).