# How do you get the player game object from rotating with the sphere game object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation

I am currently making a Katamari/Billy Hatcher game where the player has to roll spheres around. When the game starts the player has normal platformer controls until it approaches a sphere and if the player presses the "attach" button, the player becomes a child of the sphere. The issue I am having is whenever this happens, the player rotates with the sphere. I tried freezing the player's rigid body so it can stop rotating but that just stops the sphere's rotation. Is there any way to stop the rotation of the player, while keeping the sphere rotating?

Picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1iZN.png)
Here's my scripts for the process:

```
Rigidbody hitRB;
public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
public LayerMask pickupMask;
bool isAttached;


private void TouchingGum()
{
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    foreach (GameObject gumball in gumBalls)
    {
        
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Attach") && Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.forward, out hit, attachRequireDistance, pickupMask))
        {
            isAttached = true;
            Debug.Log(true);
        }
        else
        {
            isAttached = false;
        }
    }


    if (isAttached)
    {
        hitRB = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Vector3 heldOffset = transform.right * offset.x + transform.up * offset.y + transform.forward * offset.z;
        hitRB.isKinematic = true;
        hitRB.MovePosition(player.transform.position + heldOffset);
    }
    else if(!isAttached && !hitRB == null)
    {
        hitRB.isKinematic = false;
    }
```

Comment: I would just make a script to have the player follow the position instead of childing it. That way the player and Sphere have their own rotation independent of each other.

Comment: You can also put them both under another empty game object

Answer (score 0):

If you can, don’t use parent/child relationships in these situations. I feel that there is always a better way. One way of accomplishing this is by taking the player’s transform, and adding the forward direction to an offset:

```
Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
LayerMask pickupMask; //change to mask of objects that can be picked up in editor.
public bool held;

void Update()
{
   RaycastHit hit;
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 2, pickupMask))
   {
       held = true;
   }
   else
   {
       held = false
   }
   Rigidbody hitRB = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   if (held)
   {
       Vector3 heldOffset = (transform.right * offset.x) + (transform.up * offset.y) + (transform.forward * offset.z);
       // if it still glitches, remove the previous line and add the line after this one.
       Vector3 heldOffset = transform.forward * offset.z;
       hitRB.isKinematic = true;
       hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = transform.position + heldOffset;
   }
   if else (!held && !hitRB == null)
   {
      hitRB.isKinematic = false;
   }
}
```

This script uses raycast and input to detect if the player is clicking the left mouse button and is looking at an object within 2 distance and with a certain layer mask. Then it will set the velocity to the offset plus the player’s position. In other words, this gets the object you looked at while pressing left click, and holds it in front of you (or whatever the offset is).

Comment: Hello tried out and modified your solution. But it seems the player isn't holding the sphere in front of him, I don't know if it has something to do with handling his offset.

        if(isAttached)
        {
            Vector3 heldOffset = player.transform.right * offset.x + player.transform.up * offset.y + player.transform.forward * offset.z;
            hitRB = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            hitRB.velocity = player.transform.position + heldOffset;
        }

Comment: If you have set the `offset` variable to (0, 0, 1), it should hold it in front of the player. If that doesn’t hold it in front of the player, tell me if it holds the object at all. If it doesn’t, then tell me that too. And describe in detail what is happening. Also, I changed the code. Check it out.

Comment: Made the changes for AttachToGum. The only changes that happened are whenever I press the "attach" button it keeps moving the sphere based on the offset in the z-axis. the player object still does not hold the sphere. Am I doing anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Is it glitching in an undesired location? I still don’t understand what is happening. Can you please describe what you see when you run the game in a few sentences.

Comment: Yeah, it’s glitching, whenever I press the “attach” button the sphere keeps moving around. The player doesn’t have hold of the sphere. Is this still making sense?

Comment: I added some more things. Add them, and tonight, if it still glitches, I will do my best to fix it in unity (I wasn’t using unity to write these, so I didn’t know if they would work.)

Comment: Still the same result, my dude.

Comment: Sorry. Can you wait until next morning, or tonight if I work faster. Then I will post a fix if I get one.

Comment: That's fine. I'll try figuring it out myself

Comment: Okay So after a bit of finagling, I was able to get the sphere to attach to the player. The only problem is whenever I change the y-axis, the player game object can't hold it. Also, The sphere still doesn't rotate and phases through gameObjects(See pic above.)

Comment: I made this once, and the way I did it was by making a sphere prefab (the object I wanted to hold) and once I had a certain button it would Instantiate in front of me. Maybe, with the raycasting, if you know how to, then you can delete the object you raycasted at. Then you can Instantiate the sphere prefab (make sure the prefab has no Rb) and have a script on it that would set its position to `player.transform.forward * value + player.transform.position` Where player is the gameobject of the player. Detect the key that you want to drop it, and when they press that key, you should attach a

Comment: Rigidbody. Then, you should check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67140004/throw-an-object-using-physics-unity) to make a throw. Make sure to read the comments. Tell me if you would like me to write code in my answer.

Comment: Alright, Thanks, tested it out and it works!!

Comment: Click the ‘close’ button below your question, but above the comments. It should be in small text. This is to signal people that the question was solved.